# Vega : Add missing information in data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite

In kibana, In a Vega-lite visualization, I would like to create a Transition state graph  of an application (AAAA) over the time. ( timeline )  
the states have fixed values ( init , start , running ...  )

On x axis the timestamp, 
On Y the state level, 
A rectangle or bar to trace the state level.

|====
|       ======
|                  ============
______________________________
 t0          t1           t2       ....

my data  comes from a query in ElasticSearch and have the following format.

```
timestamp  app  state
  t0    AAAA  Init
  t1    AAAA  start
  t2    AAAA  Running
  t3    AAAA  stopped
```

In vega, I would like represent the state by a bar or a rectangle, 
ex:  the Init state will be represented by a rectangle starting from t0 and ending at t1. but I don't have this information ! t1 is in the next data line

Is it possible to calculate this value by exploiting the next line . 
The data will be like that.

```
timestamp  app  state    ends 
  t0    AAAA  Init         t1
  t1    AAAA  start        t2 
  t2    AAAA  Running      t3
  t3    AAAA  stopped      t4
```

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: where does t4 come from? Is it the time associated with the Init step of the next app in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a window transform using the `lead` operation to find the next value. For example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"timestamp": 0, "app": "A", "state": "init"},
      {"timestamp": 10, "app": "A", "state": "start"},
      {"timestamp": 25, "app": "A", "state": "run"},
      {"timestamp": 30, "app": "A", "state": "stop"},
      {"timestamp": 40, "app": "B", "state": "init"},
      {"timestamp": 55, "app": "B", "state": "start"},
      {"timestamp": 75, "app": "B", "state": "run"},
      {"timestamp": 85, "app": "B", "state": "stop"},
      {"timestamp": 90, "app": null, "state": "init"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"op": "lead", "field": "timestamp", "as": "t_stop"}]},
    {"filter": "datum.app != null"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "app"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "timestamp"},
    "x2": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "t_stop"},
    "y": {
      "type": "nominal",
      "field": "state",
      "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "timestamp", "order": "ascending"}
    }
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a problem to adapt this example to my context.
Timestamp is not  a direct value, but a temporal data like this :   

@timestamp: "2016-04-05T15:21:06.494Z" ...
I suppose that I have also to transform it , isnt'it ?

Comment: If you use ``"type": "temporal"`` rather than ``"type": "quantitative"`` for the timestamp data, it should work fine.